# Arrays PHP, store values into keys and retrieve then

Tags: php, arrays, amazon-web-services

I´m stuck with this problem, i´m the function i´m creating receives two params, $codeList, $priceList both of then are needed to send a XML and for each code and price one more node must be added to the XML, this the code i´m using by now, i have problems

```
$feed = '
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
  <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion> 
  <MerchantIdentifier>XXXXXXX</MerchantIdentifier> 
</Header>
  <MessageType>Price</MessageType>';
```

I create two arrays to make and example:

```
$SKU = array('ASUSVNA1','esx','rer','ASUSasVNA1','itemsdasd','item 24');
$price = array(2,3,4,5,6,7);
```

then i do this :

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($price as $price) {

foreach ($SKU as $SKU) {
  $i++;
  $feed .='
  <Message>
    <MessageID>'.$i.'</MessageID> 
    <Price>
      <SKU>'.$SKU.'</SKU> 
      <StandardPrice currency="USD">'.$price.'</StandardPrice> 
      </Price>
  </Message>';
}



}


  $feed .= '
</AmazonEnvelope>';
```

Works to create the XML but in the output this message is send : Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using different name for array and vars

```
  $i = 0;
  foreach ($price as $my_price) {

    foreach ($SKU as $my_SKU) {
      $i++;
      $feed .='
      <Message>
        <MessageID>'.$i.'</MessageID> 
        <Price>
          <SKU>'.$my_SKU.'</SKU> 
          <StandardPrice currency="USD">'.$my_price.'</StandardPrice> 
          </Price>
      </Message>';
    }
  }
```

Comment: Very accurate now the problem is that he is printing 6*6 times the node <Message>, seems like my approach is bad, gotta find another way.

Comment: @AlejandroTorres   you should look  at how  operate a single foreach on both the array .. take a search for this  ..

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your variables in foreach.
You should change $price to $prices, $SKU to $SKUs and then use like this:

```
$SKUs = array('ASUSVNA1','esx','rer','ASUSasVNA1','itemsdasd','item 24');
$prices = array(2,3,4,5,6,7);
foreach ($prices as $price) {
    foreach ($SKUs as $SKU) {
        //the rest of code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is why it's not working, but in a foreach statement, I would never use $var as $var. I would always do like $vars as $var or something. Not sure if they step on each other or not, but that may be what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The answers we´re all correct it was a mistake of my part, however a problem came from doing the code that way because it was printing 6*6 times the nodes of  i found another way to solve this:

```
$SKU = array('ASUSVNA1','esx','rer','ASUSasVNA1','itemsdasd','item 24');
$price = array(2,3,4,5,6,7);
```

Created this variable to store both array

```
$result_array = [
  'sku'   => '',
  'price' => ''
];
```

storing the SKU here

```
 foreach ($SKU as $SKU) {
  $result_array['sku'][] = $SKU;
 }
```

Storing the price

```
 foreach ($price as $price) {
  $result_array['price'][] = $price;
 }
```

Now create a foreach over the index 'sku' as $index => $value, $index will allow me to count every record in that array ( there are 6 in this case on both so for this example is good), now the tricks come in the node of :

**StandardPrice currency="USD">'.$result_array['price'][$index].'**

the [$index] allows me to travel all the index in my result_array['price'] index

```
 $i = 0;

 foreach ($result_array['sku'] as $index => $value) {

  $i++;
  $feed .='
  <Message>
    <MessageID>'.$i.'</MessageID> 
    <Price>
      <SKU>'.$value.'</SKU> 
      <StandardPrice currency="USD">'.$result_array['price'][$index].'</StandardPrice> 
      </Price>
  </Message>';

}

 $feed .= '
</AmazonEnvelope>';
```

problem solved, thank you to everyone.